# Bertini for normality: a general hyperplane section of a normal variety is normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a normal (complex) projective variety. There is an old paper by Seidenberg which shows that a general hyperplane section of $X$ is normal.

Does anyone know a modern proof (or reference) for this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cross-site duplicate of [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282781/bertinis-type-theorems-over-imperfect-fields/297934#297934). This is a community-wiki post recording the accepted answer to that question by [Takumi Murayama](https://mathoverflow.net/users/33088/takumi-murayama). The section below the horizontal separator is a copy-paste of that post.

---

I needed to know the answer to this myself, so here is a good reference:

> Hubert Flenner, Liam O’Carroll, and Wolfgang Vogel, *Joins and
> intersections,* Springer Monographs in Mathematics, Springer-Verlag,
> Berlin, 1999. MR [1724388](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1724388) DOI [10.1007/978-3-662-03817-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-03817-8)

The relevant results are the following:

**Theorem 3.4.10.** *Let $X$ be a variety over an infinite field $K$, and let $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$. Assume that $\Gamma \subseteq \lvert D \rvert$ is a finite-dimensional linear system that is not composed with a pencil and satisfies $\operatorname{codim} \operatorname{Bs}(\Gamma) \ge 2$. Then, a generic member of $\Gamma$ is irreducible.*

**Corollary 3.4.14.** *Let $X \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n_K$ be a projective scheme over an infinite field $K$ which is regular (resp. normal, reduced, satisfies $R_k$). Then, for a generic hyperplane $H \subseteq \mathbf{P}^n_K$, the intersection $X \cap H$ has the same property.*